# Looking for spec. of PHP Internal session format in order to share session information between PHP and another framework

Tags: php, session, web-frameworks

I'm looking an ability to decode and encode internal PHP session format.

There is way to create custom session handler in PHP

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php

However I'm looking for a method to understand its content. For example I want that
that in PHP `$_SESSION("user_id")` and in some other framework `session().get("user_id")` would return the same string.

The only stuff I found is: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-encode.php
and it only says it is internal format.

Is there any reference documentation for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You find a lot of documentation (see the [`README` file](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized) and the [`docs` folder](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized/tree/master/docs)) of that within the [Serialized PHP Library](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized), it also allows you to change the format into XML and other formats.

> SERIALIZE TYPE IDENTIFICATION CHARS
>
> In a serialized string, each chunk of data is prefixed by a single character (case sensitive) signalling the type (a-z sorted):
>
> - a - Array
> - b - Boolean
> - C - Object implementing serializeable Interface
> - d - Float
> - i - Integer
> - N - NULL
> - O - Object
> - r - Recursion
> - R - Recursion by Reference
> - s - String
> - S - Encoded String (PHP 6 upwards compatibility)

The library supports as well session serialization which is very close to standard value serialization and outlined in the docs, too.

Comment: It seems to be a nice library but its license is too restrictive AGPL. In any case thanks!

Comment: AGPL is cool. If you have a problem with that, there are commercial offerings, just call the author.

Comment: The problem I need to use the code in some FOSS project with much less restrictive license