# Php Serialization Format

Tags: php, serialization

I'm trying to use the Python phpserialize library to read serialized session data from PHP. However, I discovered that my PHP setup is saving session data in a format that is different from what phpserialize (and pretty much all other documentation across the web) expects. For example:

```
$_SESSION["userid"] = 42;
echo session_encode();
```

prints out

```
userid|i:42;
```

whereas phpserialize serializes this as:

```
phpserialize.serialize({'userid':42})
'a:1:{s:6:"userid";i:42;}'
```

I checked the session.serialize_handler through phpinfo() and it's set to 'php' (the other options being php_binary and wddx). I cannot use any of the standard php serialization libraries in python as a result. Any suggestions?

Comment: *`session_encode` - Please note the serialization method is not the same as `serialize()`. The serialization method is internal to PHP can can be set using `session.serialize_handler`.*

Comment: try json_encode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @decereé I'm not using the php serialize() function anywhere, but need to know what I have to do to have session_encode() in php and python phpserialize.unserialize() to be able to talk to each other.

Comment: `serialize` is *the* PHP serialization format that phpserialize emulates. The above is saying that session data is saved in another format that is not the same as *the* PHP serialization format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for spec. of PHP Internal session format in order to share session information between PHP and another framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824951/looking-for-spec-of-php-internal-session-format-in-order-to-share-session-infor)

Comment: @decereé - Thanks, I realize that I need a different php serialization library than phpserialize, one that can handle 'flat' session variables, that are not part of an encapsulating hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be calling `serialize` on the `$_SESSION` array if you want to pass this from PHP to Python.

Example:

```
echo serialize($_SESSION);
```

The result will then be interpreted by the PHP serialization lib.

`session_encode` is NOT the same as `serialize`.

Answer (score 1):

On PHP you serialize variable and in Python you serialize array.

This code:

```
$data = array('userid' => 42);
echo json_encode($data);
```

will show you the same result as phpserialize do.

But it's better to use json_encode/json_decode to transfer data between php application & python application.